# Pivot data of weekdays into column

Tags: sql-server

My query returns data for every day of week in row format but I need to get it in column format. What is the best way to achieve this?

The original data is:

```
Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday <br/>
10       15       18        20          25         18       21
```

I need to convert it into

```
Sunday   | 10
Monday   | 15
Tuesday  | 18
Wednesday| 20
Thursday | 25
Friday   | 18
Saturday | 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UNPIVOT` keyword here, like so:

```
select colname,value from
yourtable
unpivot
(
 value
 for colname in (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday)
) as u
order by colname
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ce14/1)

Comment: That's exactly what was required. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Funnily enough, you were almost there in your question title when you said `PIVOT`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

SELECT ColNames,Data 
    FROM   YourTable 
           CROSS APPLY ( VALUES ('Sunday', Sunday), 
                                ('Monday ', Monday ), 
                                ('Tuesday ', Tuesday ), 
                                ('Wednesday', Wednesday),
                                ('Thursday ', Thursday ),
                                ('Friday', Friday),
                                ('Saturday ', Saturday ),
    ) V(ColNames, Data)
```